# React router v4 doesnt work as I want to

Tags: reactjs, router

i have problem with react router v4. Here's my setup:

```
  <Router>
    <div className="container">
      <Header />

      <Route exac path="/" component={Landing} />
      <Route path="/realmadrid" component={Realmadrid} />
      <Route path="/live" component={Live} />
      <Route path="/news" component={News} />
      <Route path="/archives" component={Archives} />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

As you can imagine.. doesnt work. Only main path '/' is showing corretcly.

Comment: Do you have some errors on a console?

Comment: No but actually it behaves a little bit different than I said before. It renders the Landing component in every route. Only last component (archive) is rendered with landing component when im in /live, /news, /realmadrid or /archives.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to wrap your routes to `<Switch>` [tag](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) that renders only the first Route child that matches the location. Without that the router will render every Route that matches the location inclusively.

```
<Router>
    <div className="container">
      <Header />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <Route path="/realmadrid" component={Realmadrid} />
          <Route path="/live" component={Live} />
          <Route path="/news" component={News} />
          <Route path="/archives" component={Archives} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
```